# Update an ASP.NET Web Application by dropping the DLL on the web server

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is it possible to update the ASP.NET dll on IIS server in case of a multiple projects web application after I modified and rebuilt it?

I'd expect to follow this workflow:

1. There is a working ASP.NET application with multiple projects (web, data, utility, etc.)
2. I modify the web project in Visual Studio and rebuild it.
3. I replace its dll with the new one in IIS.
4. I restart IIS.

Would that work?

Comment: Is "Hm?" your question? Read [ask]. While not an ideal deployment scenario, what you describe should just work, unless you make incompatible changes. In that case you'll have an error you can research.

Comment: Why, please, please?

Comment: There is a question at the top with a 'please' in the end. :)

Comment: The answer is _"Yes, this should work"_. If it did, you wouldn't have to ask a question. So it's obvious it doesn't work. Therefore I recommend you to read [ask] and ask an actually answerable question.

Comment: I see, but I do not want to bother with the other parts of the code because this is a legacy app.

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Is your question really just _"Is this possible"_? So you'll be happy if someone posts _"Yes"_ as an answer? If so, then why didn't you try it for yourself?

Comment: Adding "I would like somebody to help me" to the end of your question doesn't improve it at all. You need to ask a valid question in the first place. Did you read CodeCaster's last message? His point is that you can try what you've described yourself to see if it works or not. If it works, then great, no need to waste your or our time with a question on Stack Overflow. If it doesn't work, then you need to specifically describe what you did, and what went wrong so that you'll have a specific answerable question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have much time to test it. I know 'I make it I learn it', but I thought that somebody say a 'No' or 'Yes' with a few extra advices because I've never done it before. Sorry again.

Comment: If you don't have time to try it, why bother asking if it's possible? We can ask hypothetical questions all day, but do they really matter if you're not planning on actually acting upon the information you receive?

Comment: Nice. A bantch of comments for nothing. I'm starting to think you do not even know how to do it. Never mind! :D

Comment: People here do this in their free time without getting payed for it. If you want help, do something for it. Answers without effort will get downvoted because it looks like you want free help like from the next best customer support.

Comment: Questions without effort* I should sleep some more...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this Just Works™. What you want to do is a so-called "bin deploy". You just overwrite (after backing up of course) the (relevant files in the) `bin` directory of the web application, IIS detects this and restarts your application, so you can even skip step four.

That's all there is to it. So as long as you compile against the same assemblies already present on the web server, meaning you don't call methods or use types not present in the assemblies the server or cause other issues that prevent the DLL from being loaded or executed, you can just drop the newly compiled DLL into the web application and the site will run using your new code.